# Login and authentication system with .txt file

Tags: java, authentication

I'm trying to code a simple login system with authentication.
I first try to give user two choices of login or registering.
Then if user chose to register, and the information will be stored in the .txt file to then used to compare with the login details to check whether this user existed or password is valid.
I encountered a problem which is that when I registered two or more 'accounts',
I'm able to login the other accounts other than the first account.
It seems like something is missing in term of 'reading' through the .txt file, finding the data.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    File file = new File("database.txt");
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Customers customer = new Customers();

    System.out.println("1. Login");
    System.out.println("2. Register");

    int option = keyboard.nextInt();

    switch (option) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("LOGIN PAGE");
            System.out.println("Username: ");
            String inpUser = keyboard.next();

            if (input.next().equals(inpUser)) {
                System.out.println("Password: ");
                String inpPass = keyboard.next();
                if (input.next().equals(inpPass)) {
                    System.out.println("Login Succesful!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Password is incorrect.");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Username is incorrect.");
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("REGISTRATION PAGE");
            System.out.println("Username: ");
            String username = keyboard.next();
            customer.setUsername(username);


            System.out.println("Password: ");
            String password = keyboard.next();
            customer.setPassword(password);

            System.out.println("You've successfully registered! You may login now.");

            output.println(customer.getUsername());
            output.println(customer.getPassword());

            output.close();
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("1 OR 2 PLEASE");
    }
    keyboard.close();
    input.close();
}
```

Customers code

```
public Customers(){

}

public Customers(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

Comment: provide `Customers` code please

Comment: Could you narrow down a problem? Seems you overwrite your file or something

Comment: `if (input.next().equals(inpPass)){` --> this will always take the first line of your `file` when comparing with the user's password.

Comment: @AlexSikilinda
Edited.

Comment: @xuesheng
I'm lacking of the part which the system will read through the txt file.

Comment: @Mena
What to change to make it scan through the whole file? As in finding the right data to compare?

Answer (score 0):

You're only checking if the user input is equal to the first row in your .txt file.

```
if (input.next().equals(inpUser)){
```

You need to check every entry. To do so you need to iterate over every row in your file. Something like this should do it.

```
case 1:
System.out.println("LOGIN PAGE");
System.out.println("Username: ");
String inpUser =  keyboard.next();
boolean found = false;
while(input.hasNext() && !found) { // Add a loop here to chek for every entry in the file
    if (input.next().equals(inpUser)){
        System.out.println("Password: ");
        String inpPass = keyboard.next();
        if (input.next().equals(inpPass)){
            System.out.println("Login Succesful!");
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    } 
}
if(!found) {
    System.out.println("Login incorrect!");
}
```

Comment: I've tried using this, but it'll show me all the result it compared with. 
For example, i key in the exact same thing in first line of text file as username, and exact same thing in second line of text file as password. It will show me that the login is successful, but add on the other two Username is incorrect, because it scanned through the third and forth data in the text file too.

Comment: @Sean my bad. I added a break in the correct if branch to terminate the loop.

Comment: I tried to add break into every System.out.println
Then I tried to key in the details of second account I registered.
Right after i key in the second username, it shows me username is incorrect, which I suspect it didn't really gone through the whole text file. I'm a ittlle confused.

Comment: @Thats not really the right way to go. 
Take a look at my new version

Comment: With the new version, it works better. But is there anyway that I can specify whether it's username incorrect or password incorrect?

Comment: @Sean well thats something I would not do in general. Take a look here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17816/username-and-or-password-invalid-why-do-websites-show-this-kind-of-message-i